# obfuscator and linker for .net

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, linker, desktop-application

I am in need to develop a desktop application which will be quite light-weight but dont want my end users to install full-fledged .net framerwork to run that. I've done a lot of research and my findings are:
1. using some .net linkers, i can achieve this goal. some of them are salamander, spoon.net(not 100% sure about its functionality), rustemsoft etc.
2. I am coming across two tools for this: Obfuscator & linker. Now I know obfuscator basically is used to eliminate the reverse-engineering possibilities of a code and to secure it but i've  found that many obfuscators also include .net linker feature

so kindly can anyone enlighten me that for me to achieve my goal: running my .net developed application in end user's Windows (XP to be precise - though its quite defunct), can i use some obfuscators like that of rustemsoft to create a standalone and ready to deploy exe with no dependencies on framework?

Comment: Why not use native C++ instead of C#/.NET if you don't want any framework dependencies?

Comment: If you target an older version of the framework, they likely have it already installed. Tools such as this are usually very expensive so it may be cost prohibitive

Comment: @thiefMaster: Are there going to be any compromises in terms of efficiency, UI design and functionality if we resort to using C++ instead of C# to develop our desktop application? Actually the desktop application is database driven (we are considering to use SQlite) and also we want the local data of the application to sync with our online server as well. So what, in your expert opinion, the challenges we may face if we prefer C++ over C# for such application development?

Comment: Well, C# is somewhat easier simply because you don't have to care about memory management and have an easy-to-use GUI toolkit (WinForms or WPF)...

Comment: PheonixReborn: Yes unfortunately in our target market, Windows XP is quite dominant and what we've found after searching online, that Windows XP doesnt come with any version of .net framework installed in it by default. We are expecting our application to be of max 10MB size but in order to run this in those system where there isnt any .net framework, installing .net framework (whose size can be around 200-400MB+) before running our application doesnt seem to be a valid and practical proposition...

Comment: @ThiefMaster :: Yes but what if we cater the memory management issues (manually reserving and releasing the memory during the coding), will there be any difference from user's experience perspective? I've read that Qt is a framework available for C++ for developing attractive GUI in C++ for desktop application. do you think using that we can build attractive UI in C++ competitive to C#?

Comment: Qt is fine. No matter if you use C#/.NET or C++ (either with native WinAPI calls or Qt) - the UI can look/behave just the same way.